# What is the difference between PATH and $PATH in .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, unix

The context for the following is that I've been playing with Node.js and npm, and want to make sure they're correctly installed.

I understand `.bash_profile` is a config file for Bash. And it's where you set your environmental variable `PATH`. What I'm not clear on is the difference between `PATH` and `$PATH`, as in:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

What's the dollar sign doing? Would you help me understand the difference with an example?

Comment: That code is adding "/usr/local/bin" to PATH.  PATH is the variable and $PATH is how you access the variable

Comment: If you assign something to a variable use PATH.

Comment: @codeforester - Is the `$PATH` in the assignment even necessary then? Could it be written as:
`export PATH=/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: This  concatenates `/usr/local/bin:` and the content of variable PATH and then overwrites variable PATH with this new content.

Comment: `PATH` is for assignment, `$PATH` is for reading the variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is very basic BASH stuff. With the $-sign you refer to the content of the variable. An example:

```
a=text
echo a
echo $a
```

gives you

```
a
text
```

So, in the example above,

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

will put /usr/local/bin, followed by a colon and then followed by the original content of the PATH-variable in PATH. If you would do

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:PATH
```

the PATH-variable would contain the literal word `PATH` and not the previous content of the PATH-variable.

You should get some introductory material into the bash, for example at tldp.org.

Comment: Please *don't* point folks at TLDP's ABS -- it's the W3Schools of bash, full of bad-practice examples and outdated content. The [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) are three preferable sources.